# Button not changing color onClick

Tags: android, button, colors

I think I've got the required stuff. I want to change the color of my button on state_pressed. I've got the following resources:

color.xml in values with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue">#045FB4</color>
    <color name="clicked">#A9E2F3</color>
</resources>
```

button_dashboard in the drawable folder with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/clicked" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

And finally this Button in my layout:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/button_dashboard"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Am I doing something wrong? I haven't written any onClick code yet because that's not required at this point (just experimenting).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change...text color or background color? Because you are using color as drawable ...

Comment: Background. Rather than using PNGs, I just want to use plain colors as backgrounds.

Comment: If you want to do that you should create custom drawable using these colors and set the drawables as background, not the color.

Comment: @Asim you can take advantage of <shape> in this case,, take a look at my answer..

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:drawable="@color/clicked" android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@color/blue" />


    </selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change content of button_dashboard in the drawable folder to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/clicked" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/blue" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And finally this Button in your layout:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/button_dashboard"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

use this one
drawable/selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/Red"/>
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/Red" />
     <item android:drawable="@color/White" /> 
</selector>
```

and set as background of button in oncreate method

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your button layout:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

So the button in your layout should now be:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_dashboard"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more line to your button_dashboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/clicked" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/clicked" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" />

</selector>
```

After this please add one line code to your button click listener

```
button2.setSelected(true);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:state_pressed="true">        
        <color android:color="@color/clicked" />    
    </item>    
    <item android:state_pressed="false">        
        <color android:color="@color/blue" />    
    </item>
 </selector>
```